# ansible 2.6.17 and pbrun su - user

Tags: ansible, pbrun

I am testing ansible with pbrun. We ssh to the server using our own credential and then once ssh, we run pbrun su - orasoa to be able to install oracle binaries and domains.

I am testing 2 of my dev box

```
inventory
[soa]
soaserver1.mycompany.com
soaserver2.mycompany.com
```

ansible 2.6.17

my ansible.cfg

```
inventory = inventory
remote_user      = oracl
ask_pass      = True
host_key_checking = false

[privilege_escalation]
become=True
become_method=pbrun
become_user=orasoa
become_ask_pass=True
```

Ansible logs

```
<soaserver1.mycompany.com.hphc.org> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: 
mmonter2
<soaserver1.mycompany.com.hphc.org> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d14 ssh -vvv -C -o 
ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 
User=mmonter2 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 
ControlPath=/home/orasoa/.ansible/cp/ae14ca51a1 -tt 
soaserver1.mycompany.com.hphc.org '/bin/sh -c '"'"'pbrun  -u orasoa 
 '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-zarafuemqzepjtglwquygnwehlgwpkso; 
/usr/bin/python /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1571850508.16- 
236952200511820/ping.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
<soaserver1.mycompany.com.hphc.org> (0, '', 'OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 
1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013\ndebug1: Reading configuration data 
/etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto- 
mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: 
mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: 
mux_client_request_forwards: requesting forwardings: 0 local, 0 
remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3:   
mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: 
done pid = 27594\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request 
sent\r\ndebug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 
2\r\ndebug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2\r\ndebug3: 
mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: 
Received exit status from master 0\r\n')
fatal: [soaserver1.mycompany.com.hphc.org]: FAILED! => changed=false
  module_stderr: |-
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
debug3: mux_client_request_forwards: requesting forwardings: 0 local, 0 
 remote
debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 27594
debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
debug2: Received exit status from master 127
Shared connection to soaserver1.mycompany.com.hphc.org closed.
 module_stdout: |-
pbrun9.2.0-08[26134]: Request rejected by pbmasterd on lnlog004.hphc.org.
msg: MODULE FAILURE
 rc: 127
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's unclear what the question is here - please edit your post (button at bottom).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this option in ansible.cfg {uncomment ssh_args}

```
[ssh_connection]

# ssh arguments to use
# Leaving off ControlPersist will result in poor performance, so use
# paramiko on older platforms rather than removing it, -C controls compression use
ssh_args = -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=30m
```

Comment: I got it to work with
    [privilege_escalation]
     become_method='pbrun'  
     become_user='oraosa'
     become_ask_pass=True